# Distribution of the difference of two random variables (solution provided only approval needed)...

Tags: probability

I am tyring to find the distribution of the following $$Z=U-V=cos(X)-cos(Y)$$$$X \sim U[-\pi,\pi]$$
$$Y \sim U[-\pi,\pi]$$

**My solution**
The cosines of the angles are distributed as $$U:=cos(X)$$

$$ f_U(u) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}} & \mbox{if $-1\leq u \leq 1$};\\
          0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right. $$

Then the distribution of the difference can be derived by convolution $$Z=U-V$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{\max(-1,-1-z)}^{\min(1,1-z)}  \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-(v+z)^2}}  \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-v^2}}
\,dv$$

I am not sure about the integral limits, I got them as follows $$ -1 \leq v\leq 1$$
$$-1 \leq v+z \leq 1\rightarrow -1-z\leq v\leq 1-z $$

Thanks for any help regarding the limits...

**Update**

The answer below provides a different approach, I want to make sure that mine is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Z be a continuous random variable equal to the difference of the continuous random variables U and V.  To compute $f_Z(z)$ we integrate $f_UV(u,v)$ along the line where $u-v = z$ or $v = u-z$.

Then $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_U(u).f_V(u-z)du $$

$$f_U(u) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

$$f_V(u-z) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-(u-z)^2}}$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_U(u).f_V(u-z)du $$

$$-1<u-z<1 => z-1<u<1+z$$

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{max(-1,z-1)}^{min(1,1+z)} \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-(u-z)^2}}du , |z| \le 2$$
$$ = 0, elsewhere$$

Comment: Thanks, but you made me more confused. Can you please keeep the integration with respect to $v$...Also I think the limits of the integration are wrong they should me min instead of max and max instead of min

Comment: The integrand should ideally cover $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and should be real. Taking this into account, the integrand is split into $\sqrt{1-u^2} $ and $\sqrt{1-(u-z)^2}$, which means, u should lie between -1 and 1 and u-z should lie between -1 to 1.  Taking the prior statement into account, it should be maximum of (-1, z-1) and minimum of (1,1+z). Sorry, I have edited it. You have started out defining Z = U-V and hence the notation with U.  If you want you could define Z = V-U and proceed with the notation with V ( basically convert every u to v.  There should not be any confusion.

Comment: given the fact that $ u\leq 1$ and $ u\leq 1+z $, this mean that $u$ should be less than the both $1+z$ and 1 which is equivalent to saying minimum of $(1+z,1)$....

Comment: I have already edited it.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thanks, so this means what I have above is correct?

Comment: Yes. Inequalities are always a nightmare

Comment: what do you mean by inequalities are nighmare?

Comment: In general, inequalities are in general hair risers, I have spent hours in more difficult problems than this with complex region of integration.  If you are in the right mind,you will get it instantly, if not it takes some time to figuring it out. That is what I meant

Comment: @satishramanathan excellent treatment, would though be great if you could add that $f_Z(z)$ is zero outside $|z|\leq 2$, and takes the form you nicely derived, otherwise.

Comment: @Mehdi, Thanks for your compliment. I shall certainly add the additional information.